# how can i pass this date value to firebase

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, dart

trying to pass the date and time string values to firebase using the following flutter code

```
final DateAndTimeRef = database.child('DateAndTime/');
String dateString = DateTime.now().toString();


 RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Turn OFF"),
              onPressed: () async {
                try {
                  DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                
                  String convertedDateTime =
                      "${now.year.toString()}-${now.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${now.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')} ${now.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${now.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";
                  await DateAndTimeRef.set({'datetime': convertedDateTime});
                  print("Saving data to firebase OFF");
                } catch (e) {
                  print("error2");
                }
              }),
```

what is the problem?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Josteve Exception has occurred.
FirebaseException ([firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelDatabaseReference.set (package:firebase_database_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_database_reference.dart:78:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _ControlingState.build.<anony ...

Comment: Check if you have created the Firestore database on the console also check your security rules to make sure user can write to the database.